# Pair a PC via bluetooth to send keyboard commands

Tags: android, ios, macos, bluetooth

Is it possible to send keyboard commands to Mac/Windows system with Android/iOS app using bluetooth . I am trying to pair mac with an Android device and write keyboard commands to the services using bluetooth .

Any comments/help on feasibility , limitations would be a great help .

Comment: An iOS app cannot implement the HID Bluetooth profile, so no, it isn't possible using iOS.

Comment: Is is possible in Android ?